# QGIS GRASS using v.drape FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/osgeo-grass/7.6.1_5/grass76/etc/lock':

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I'm running QGIS 3.8.3 and am trying to use v.drape. When I run it from the processing toolbox, I get a FileNotFoundError that's pointing to a strange /usr/local/Cellar/osgeo-grass.... folder.

I'm running OSX 10.14.6

I'm not sure where it's grabbing that user directory. I've been a constant upgrader over the years, so not sure if there is some older dependency or something that needs to be update... or even where to start.

Full log is:

```
         Starting GRASS GIS...
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2207, in 
         main()
         File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 2143, in main
         grass_gui=grass_gui)
         File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 1390, in lock_mapset
         ret = call([gpath("etc", "lock"), lockfile, "%d" % os.getpid()])
         File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/bin/_grass76", line 247, in call
         return subprocess.call(cmd, **kwargs)
         File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 323, in call
         with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
         restore_signals, start_new_session)
         File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
         raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
         FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/osgeo-grass/7.6.1_5/grass76/etc/lock': '/usr/local/Cellar/osgeo-grass/7.6.1_5/grass76/etc/lock'
         /Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/grass7/grass76.sh: line 20: /private/var/folders/p4/212f8sh94g5fyf4ys8bw39yc0000gn/T/processing_7c31a02da3a34505a56e56b476bb1792/grassdata/temp_location/PERMANENT: is a directory
```

Comment: Does the directory /usr/local/Cellar/osgeo-grass/7.6.1_5/grass76/etc/ exist (and contain files)?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm not sure where it's actually getting the "Cellar" user directory name. Looks like the bug reported here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31390 Anyone else having something like this?

Comment: There is now a fix in QGIS: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Mac-Packager/commit/ee7648f2e6ad940252c8caaeb37875d4723f90a0

Answer (score 0):

I had installed QGIS from the installer on the QGIS site. Below that installer was a link to an installer on KyngChaos's site (same version... probably different compile). Downloaded that installer and followed through the installation to get rid of the error.